how to add Aspire to blazor webassembly standalone app in .net 8
when i create new blazor webassembly project in visual studio i check the enlist in .net aspire orchestration box and it will be add to my project

but when I started my project I couldn't see any blazor project running on Aspire

I have a few project with APIs and single blazor webassembly project and I want to add Aspire to them but it doesn't run blazor webassembly part
and also I tried to add it manually so my API was added but for blazor webassembly I getting error


In the host project add a project reference to the WebAssembly application.
In the program.cs of the Host project BlazorApp38.AppHost add.

Select the WebAssembly project.

The source generator should then kick in. Projects.BlazorApp38 should be defined.
In program.cs cs simply add
builder.AddProject<Projects.BlazorApp38>("webapp");

var builder = DistributedApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.AddProject<Projects.BlazorApp38>("webapp");
builder.Build().Run();

It should look like this.
Remember this app will be running in the clients browser..

I recommend using a hosted app with something like yarp to proxy to the internal api's of the distributed app, that's the point of using a framework like Aspire right?. The client can make secure calls to its host which uses a reverse proxy to resolve the internal aspire endpoint(s).

Your answer didn't work, so I update my question and I added the error, which I'm getting for BlazorApp38_AppHost

@Regestea You added a reference to the host not the webapp. I'll add some more steps to make it clearer.

Hi Brian - Looking to solve this problem this morning and came across your answer.  I downloaded the Repo and when I ran it, it errored just like my own guess at how to implement this.  Any ideas? - will ask as a new question if the repo works for you [which I'm guessing it should!]

@MrCakaShaunCurtis I have had issues with Aspire if I install the .net 9 sdk. Have you?

That's possible it.  Will investigate.
